# Speed up linear time comparison between two arrays?

Tags: algorithm

I have a speed bottleneck in my code right now. The following function compares two arrays (position and size) and produces a new array of position elements that are smaller than size. This runs in O(n) time but is called many times. Is there anyway for me to do better for this very specific case?

code:

```
function findValidDimensions(positions, sizes) {
    var forwardDimensions = [];
    var backwardDimensions = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
        if (positions[i] < sizes[i]) {
            forwardDimensions.push(i);
        }
        if (positions[i] > 1) {
            backwardDimensions.push(i);
        }
    }

    // we can go forward or backward
    return {
        "forward": forwardDimensions,
        "backward": backwardDimensions
    }
}
```

Comment: is this question [language-agnostic](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info)?

Comment: I'm using JS, so that's the preference, but any answer would be awesome. I just hope to do better than O(n) generally.

Comment: how does your input data look like?

Comment: You'll probably need to take a step back and look at the bigger picture. That bit of code is as fast as it can be big O wise. However, looking at the code, there is a fair chance the way you are using that code could be made more efficient. So the real question is: What are you using that code for?

Comment: Well, since you are only returning one of the two lists that you build, an obvious speedup seems to be to only build the one you are going to return :) Another thing: you're not saying what language/RTL this is, but for some I bet the `.push` calls will be the bottleneck and pre-allocating the array to the max size (sizes.length) and then trimming afterwards _could_ yield a significant improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there are elements you can avoid looking at (which, from your spare description, sounds unlikely), looking at *n* elements will take O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

As i know that the complicity for your method is to large if you use a big array the best searching pattern is the heap or the B-Tree :)

Some ref :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Comment: This doesn't take into account the time to *build* such a structure.

Comment: Yes im with you but if you want to use a big data the complicity will be so huge because you compare and also you using a linear method i recommended that you take a look at the B-tree and The Heap :)